# Google Map Markers unresponsive with Ionic Bundle reference

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have google map markers that load correctly in my app, but are unresponsive to touch (e.g. no display labels).

I deduced the problem to something in the ionic bundle.

At the top of [this example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a8j99twb3y9n2ib/Working%20and%20Nonworking%20reference%20to%20Google%20Maps%20%28angularjs%20vs%20ionic%20bundle%29.html?dl=0), you will see two references:

```
    <!--With the reference below, map markers respond to touch on mobile device (iPhone)-->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!--With the reference below, map markers DO NOT respond to touch on mobile device (iPhone)-->
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

If I reference only angularjs, then I can click on the markers and get the title.

If I reference ionicbundle (which contains angularjs), clicking on the markers does nothing on my mobile device (iPhone).

It DOES still work with browser testing.

NOTE:  If you decide to test the ionic bundle, you will need to change this line:

```
angular.module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
```

to this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic','uiGmapgoogle-maps'])
```

in order for the ionic framework to load correctly.

Also, just FYI, then ionic bundle references 1.3.6 as opposed to 1.3.3.  You can change the anguarjs reference to 1.3.6 and it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

[Perry Govier](https://github.com/perrygovier) gave me the answer on [GitHub](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3391#issuecomment-85536924):

Add `data-tap-disabled="true"` to #map_canvas